# docker private registry within local network

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've set up a private registry for docker, everything works greate from outside (i've a server with several VMs, one of these is the reposiotry).

From my pc I can do `docker login  -u USER -p PASS repo.mydomain.com` and it works great.

Now, from inside another VMs if i do the same i get back `Error response from daemon: Get https://repo.mydomain.com/v1/users/: dial tcp 10.236.8.111:443: getsockopt: connection refused`

It seems that the `repo.mydomain.com` is resolved at the local (intramachine) IP, and then the repository hangsup or does not allow the connection to pass by. Or other reasons which I don't know now.

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the workaround is to use it as insecure docker repository, since intercomunication is within the local network. to do so:

- edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` adding `{ "insecure-registries":["repo.mydomain.com:5000"] }`
- restart docker `service docker restart`
- do the login using the port 5000 `docker login  -u USER -p PASS repo.mydomain.com:5000`

now it says login successfully. Wondering if there's a better (cleaner) way to do it.

PS: to pull the data you have to use `repo.mydomain.com:5000/image`